# DJI SDK iOS APP Telemetry

Tags: dji-sdk, telemetry

I am trying to get the IMU data from sensors to read out to the DJI UXSDKDemo App. The app is functioning, but I cannot figure out how to change the UI of the app such that the IMU data is printed out to the iOS device. Where would I begin to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Clarification: any method to log IMU data would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you explored the api for [Preflight Checklist](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-uilib-api/Widgets/DUXPreflightChecklistManager.html#duxpreflightchecklistmanager)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This seems like the correct avenue to explore to pull the IMUState. I think I still need to find the main loop in order to call the DUXPreflightChecklistManagerListener protocol.